# How to convert extremely small exp values to 0?

Tags: c++

I'm doing `Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization` process. At some point I'm getting output 3D vectors with values extremely small. Basically the values are `zeros`.  How to deal with values such as `-3.5527136788005009 * 10^-15`?
How to convert them to `zero` or compare if it is almost `zero`?

Comment: Typically "how to deal with" these situations is to leave the values alone.  Should "almost 1" values also be converted to 1?  Should "almost 0.25" values be converted to 0.25?

Comment: Yeah, these modifications should probably just happen as a last step when you are displaying the number to a user, if at all.

Comment: @DrewDormann in my case those almost zeros are infelicities. In case when I do 3D orthogonalization with set of 4 vectors. Where to put the 4th vector on a 3D plane that it will be linearly independent and orthogonal to other 3 vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did research on my old code and I've found this little func:

```
static const double eps = 1e-10;

bool isZero(double value) const
{
    return std::abs(value) <= eps;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You asked  "How to convert them to zero?"  If you want to convert extremely small values to zero you can use a simple `if` statement:

```
const double delta = 0.000000001;
if (x < delta && x > -delta) { x = 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, almost what I wanted. +1